# How to read the API error message from Azure APIM using the qusto query hit from c# code in Rest API

Tags: c#, azure, .net-core, azure-api-management

We have setup Azure App insights(APIM) for the API logs tracking.
In logs we are storing API url,API request payload,API response message,API response error code.
Now I need to create one api which will read the error log messages in APIM and return API error message in response.

From API we will hit a Qusto query which will fetch all the APIM logs and then those logs should be returned in the above api with the following response:

```json
{
    "Id": "1",
    "ApiUrl": "https://pd.myweb/user/{resource_id}?userId=SAM",
    "ApiErrormessage": "User SAM does not have access to the resource 1100"
}
```

I am expecting to create a Get API in dotnet core using c# which will return the response as below:
Get: fetch/logs

**Response**:

```json
{
    "Id": "1",
    "ApiUrl": "https://pd.myweb/user/{resource_id}?userId=SAM",
    "ApiErrormessage": "User sam does not have access to the resource 1100"
}
```

Comment: Please share the code what you have tried

Comment: I have not tried it yet. I just want to know how should I start this?